# how to test with pytest module from different folder

Tags: python, pytest

In my project I have the following folder structure:

```
mymodule/
   main.py
tests/
   test_main.py
```

where `test_main.py` looks like this:

```
from .mymodule.main import myfunc

def test_myfunc():
    res = myfunc()
    assert res > 1
```

I want to test it with pytest, but when I call `pytest` in the parent folder (above `mymodule` and `test`), I get `ImportError: cannot import

I tried a trick with

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
```

but it doesn't work either.

I'm using Python 3.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

First, create an empty `__init__.py` in mymodule and tests directories.

In your test_main.py file, try replacing:

- `from .mymodule.main import myfunc`
- with `from mymodule.main import myfunc`

and run `pytest` with the parent directory of mymodule and tests as the current working directory.

Comment: thanks, but this gets me: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'`

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer.